# use of word suffixes with 事

Tags: negation, suffixes

In this sentence I've a some doubts"自分　の　事し　考えぬ　には、この　氷　は　溶かせない" I think a translation would be" Think to yourself of this matter of you, this ice never will melt" But it's just a guess. I can decipher correctly this sentence. kかんがえぬ　is negative? How translate 自分のことし？

Comment: yes, 考えぬ is negative.

Comment: Thank you! so a more correct translation would be"don't think to it to yourself"?

Comment: I think that some letters are missing from the sentence.

Comment: I don't quite understand your translation, but I'm also not sure the Japanese is correct. Are you sure it is not 事しか?

Comment: My wild guess is that it is from a video game and that some of the letters are missing because they wore off.  If this is the case, then in my opinion, the question is more about the game than about Japanese.

Comment: Thank you all. Expecially User1205935 that made me realize the missing か　and おまえ。 The original sentece is "自分の事しか考えぬおまえには、この氷は溶かせない" 　without spaces. This sentece come from a manga. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: Maybe you could change the title to something more descriptive of the question (and of your accepted answer). The question is really not about 事, but more about translation.

Comment: @Shizuka Considering that you have enough rep points to access our [Chat Site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language-and-usage), you may want to ask there instead. Chat would be more suited to this type of question.

Comment: @Flaw Thank you for you suggestion. Next time I'll try the chat^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter half of your translation is right. Working from your newly corrected sentence:

自分の事しか考えぬおまえには...

自分の事 is literally "one's own things". 事 is often used with verbs like 考える to mean "(everything) about", so in this case 自分の事を考える is "to think about oneself". The noun suffix しか means (when coupled with a negative verb ending) "nothing but", so 自分の事しか考えぬ is "to think about nothing but oneself". This whole phrase is being used to describe おまえ. So the first half of the sentence comes out something like "to [someone like] you, who never thinks about anyone but themselves, ..." (with bits in [square brackets] added just to make it sound better English).

I'm not familiar with the idiom enough to tell you what the sentence actually means without context. Perhaps it's "you're so busy thinking about yourself that you don't even notice the simplest things about the rest of the world (e.g. that ice melts)", but that's a guess.

Comment: Thank you.Your step to step explanation made me understand, thanks to the context, the probable meaning of the sentence that would be" To you, who thinks about anyone but themselves, this ice will never melt". In fact the character being some sort of demon （魔物）is not expected to care for no one but himself, so he'd remain trapped under the spell. Really the context matter to fully understand. Thank you

Comment: Aha, yes, it didn't sound like an idiom I'd ever heard before. No problem.